# how to show the latest reviews on the homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9

i have found this but really don't understand what to do in step 1. Could anybody advise me. Or is there a better way to get this done.

Step1: You can get review Collection by below code:

```
$Collection=Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->addRateVotes()
                ->setDateOrder();
```

Step2: Create a Cms page from admin>Cms>Page> and at Design tab and put this code

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="review.form" template="catalog/allreview.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Step3: create allreview.phtml on app/design/frontend/your package/your template/templete/catalog/ and put below this phtml file you can put review details by below code:

```
<?php
    $_items = array_reverse( $Collection->getItems());

    foreach ($_items as $_review):
        $productId =  $_review->getentity_pk_value();
         $_review->getTitle();
         $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes();
         $_review->getDetail()
          $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()) ?>
              $this->__('[Posted %s]', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long');

    endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a module you could just put step one with step three in your catalog/allreview.phtml.

```
<?php
$Collection=Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
            ->setPageSize(1)
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
            ->addRateVotes()
            ->setDateOrder();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);         
$_items = array_reverse( $Collection->getItems());
foreach ($_items as $_review):
    $productId =  $_review->getentity_pk_value();
     $_review->getTitle();
     $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes();
     $_review->getDetail();
     $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt());
     $this->__('[Posted %s]', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long');
     echo "<ul><h3>". $_review->getTitle()."</h3>";
     echo "<li>".$_review->getDetail()."</li>";
     echo "<li>". $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt())."</li>";
endforeach;
?>
```

This can then be called within CMS page by adding below to content:

```
{block type="core/template" name="all_reviews" template="catalog/allreview.phtml"}}
```

Or below to custom layout xml:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="all.reviews" alias="reviews" template="catalog/allreview.phtml">
    </block>
</reference>
```

It is normally recommended however to use a module for the collection and then call the collection from within the phtml file in your theme.

Comment: thanks but it does nothing. i created reviews.phtml and put that in /app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog

Comment: Add this to your content in the CMS page instead of doing the layout:{{block type="core/template" name="all_reviews" template="catalog/reviews.phtml"}}</div>

Comment: i added:
1. {{block type="core/template" name="all_reviews" template="catalog/allreview.phtml"}} to the content of the page
2. added the code in allreview.phtml in app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog

still nothing, even not the content heading title.

https://www.marktbay.nl/test

Comment: So you have flushed cache in between doing these steps?

Comment: Strange how these is no footer within this page also.

Comment: i now deleted {{block......... and than the page works normal. but without the block

Comment: Is the layout within the custom layout xml within the design tab? I have this tested and working with both examples. Maybe check system.log and exception.log within var/logs

Comment: https://snag.gy/xgtQAR.jpg

Comment: sorry i don't know exactly what you mean

Comment: There are error log files  var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log they might show some errors that will help. Try the layout within the second box in image you just showed me also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60282/discussion-between-harri-and-bramvds).

Comment: @harri I have developed feedback form, code : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0    Actually it is like static image on left side, how can i display into my all pages including home page.